# Equivalente a WhereHas Laravel en Mongose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

no encuentro un solucion a esta consulta, la consulta funciona incluso lo puedo paginar, pero el problema es que me carga datos nulos, cada vez que le paso un filtro

es decir uso

```
customer:{
   usuario:{
       email:"example@example.com"
       role:"admin",
   }
}
```

seria en un caso ideal pero devido a que el filtro es por `Role` hay usuarios que no lo tienen, y me muestra en la lista tipo

```
[customer:{
    usuario: null
}]
```

en Laravel habia la funcion de `WhereHas` solo para cargar los que tubieran ese dato pero no encuentro en Mongoose

```
let result = await Cliente.paginate(
        { deleted: { $ne: true } },
        {
          ...args,
          populate: [
            "tipocliente",
            {
              path: "usuario",
              match: { role: { $regex: `.*${args?.role|| ""}.*` } },
              populate: { path: "roles" },
            },
          ],
        }
      );
```

Comment: En primer lugar, no usas el paginado de Mongoose sino un *plugin* no oficial de paginado para Mongoose ([lista de *plugins* oficiales](https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/)). En segundo lugar,  el método [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) *no se comporta como una cláusula SQL Join convencional. [Cuando no se encuentra una coincidencia](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found), el valor devuelto será siempre `null`. Esto es como una cláusla [Left JOIN SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)*. Una posible solución es usar un proceso de agregación.

Comment: @MauricioContreras si es la libreria de mongoose, incluso sin usar paginacion, los filtros los realizaré tanto en la tabla cliente y usuario, por eso si un cliente tiene usuario `null` ya no deberia devolverme, también probé con agregate y es igual, devuelve nulo, en lugar de ya no devolver el registro

Comment: *Ya no debería devolverme* es lo que tu esperas, pero no funciona así, es lo que trato de decirte en mi comentario: *Cuando no se encuentra una coincidencia, el valor devuelto será __siempre__ null*. Con agregación lo puedes hacer, o filtrando el resultado posteriormente para eliminar los valores `null`, pero `populate` directamente **siempre** devolverá `null` cuando el documento no exista. Saludos